# SQL add examples from grouping data

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Hello I have a small question in oracle SQL.
I have table Auto_Parts:

```
Category,Manufacturer_id,Part_name
Tires,Michelin, Pilot Pro
Tires,Michelin, Power One
Tires,Bridgestone, Potenza
Tires,Bridgestone, Turanza
Tires,Bridgestone, Blizzak
```

The query:

```
select Category,Manufacturer_id,count(*) cnt,example_1,example_2,example_3
  from auto_parts
group by Category,Manufacturer_id
```

result:

```
Category,Manufacturer_id,cnt  ,example_1,example_2,example_3
Tires   ,Michelin       ,1000 ,Pilot Pro,Power One,Power Two
Tires   ,Bridgestone    ,200  ,Potenza  ,Turanza  ,Blizzak
```

Question: how can I get 3 arbitrary values from the table above and present them as 3 columns in my query (a sample output is presented above, the columns are example_1,2,3)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.  Obviously you don't need the WITH block, I just used that to mimic your data, so your query would start at the "select Category..."

```
with auto_parts as
(
select 'Tires' as Category,'Michelin' as Manufacturer_id, 'Pilot Pro' as part_name from dual union all 
select 'Tires' as Category,'Michelin' as Manufacturer_id, 'Power One' as part_name from dual union all
select 'Tires' as Category,'Bridgestone' as Manufacturer_id, 'Potenza' as part_name from dual union all
select 'Tires' as Category,'Bridgestone' as Manufacturer_id, 'Turanza' as part_name from dual union all
select 'Tires' as Category,'Bridgestone' as Manufacturer_id, 'Blizzak' as part_name from dual
)
select
    Category
    Manufacturer_id,
    count(*) cnt ,
    max(case when rn = 1 then part_name end) example_1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then part_name end) example_2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then part_name end) example_3
from (
    select category, manufacturer_id, part_name, row_number() over (partition by category, manufacturer_id order by dbms_random.value) rn
    from auto_parts
)
group by Category,Manufacturer_id;
```